# Error: xcodebuild process exited with code 65 - August 2016

Tags: react-native

I installed everytying and ran the following steps:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

But I'm getting a BUILD FAIL and the following error:

```
Error: xcodebuild process exited with code 65
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (runIOS.js:102:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Any idea what is going on? I followed the exact steps from the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** Always be sure to update your Xcode folks!

---

**Protip:** And don't do it from the apple store (but always do it from an official apple website of course)

tip from: http://ericasadun.com/2016/03/22/xcode-upgrades-lessons-learned/

official apple download page: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution

first delete **ios/build** folder then run

```
sudo react-native run-ios
```

Comment: this is the one that worked for me :) sudo not necessary

Answer (score 0):

For people not wanting to download and install XCode again:

1. After updating to XCode 8, open your project and **set your signing identity right again**
2. **Run the project**, maybe it will work again. If not, you will most likely get and error from RCTWebSocket
3. Double click on the RCTWebSocket project in your navigator and **remove the flags** under build settings > custom compiler flags. Details here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8584#issuecomment-236366222

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue
mac os el capitan
xcode 7.3.1

at this time react-native@0.59.0 was release but it didn't work for me

i installed react-native with older version
and used this command and made a new project

> react-native init --version="react-native@0.53.0" myproject

now it's okay and is working perfect