# error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. i can not Run my Project

Tags: react-native, homebrew, npm-install, react-native-cli

i installed all the things as per official react-native website.
but after creating project from terminal when i try to run my project i get an error.

i used `Xcode 10` and run on latest simulater
and also already successfuly installed `node` and `watchman` with `homebrew`
then installed `npm install -g react-native-cli`

```
brew install node
brew install watchman

npm install -g react-native-cli

react-native init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

i expected to Run a Project but its shows me an error that

`"error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcodeproj"`

Comment: Anyone Please help me to solve this

Answer (score -1):

click `AwesomeProject.xcodeproj` file inside the ios folder. it will open the app to Xcode. try clean and build , then run it to the particular simualtor. post the issues , if anyone occur during run from xcode, will try to help you

> Update

Please Try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55235914/2849146

and this  answers : [Error: xcodebuild process exited with code 65 - August 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706782/error-xcodebuild-process-exited-with-code-65-august-2016)

Comment: when try to build a project in Xcode that shows me and error. "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Comment: Failed to successfully download 'folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz'. Debug info:

info ls: /Users/bjmehta/Library/Caches/com.facebook.ReactNativeBuild/folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz: No such file or directory

info shasum: /Users/bjmehta/Library/Caches/com.facebook.ReactNativeBuild/folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz: 

info Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: please try creating another project,

Comment: None of your answer is working, i already applied that. and i did not try an Android App.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to `sudo gem install cocoapods`

`cd /ios
run pod install
cd ..
delete build folder
run react-native run-ios`

if error persists,

delete build folder again
open the /ios folder in x-code
navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System

Answer (score -1):

This error is because of flipper dependency.

you can put comment on 'use flipper()' in pod file using below steps.

Go to iOS folder -> pod file -> open pod file -> comment 'use_flipper!()'-> Save -> open terminal and write 'pod install' -> run react-native run-ios

if react-native run-ios not works then open workspace on xCode and run the project from xCode. it will work.

Make sure your xCode workspace settings build system selected as New Build System.