# error Failed to build iOS project. ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I am trying to run react native on IntelliJ. My Android emulator on IntelliJ works perfectly fine however, my iOS emulator doesn't work properly and I am using MacOS X. I'm encountering issues "*error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening API.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details*."

Comment: Did you try what it instructed you to do? *To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening API.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.*

Comment: you can find answer in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725042/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I was not able to build in xcode itself but not with npx react-native run-ios in the terminal. What did it for me was to reboot my macbook and it start working.