# Updated Xcode to 12.2 / React Native 0.63.2 Build Fails

Tags: xcode, react-native

I've tried Updating Xcode Command Line, Updated CocoaPods, updated Location, and Build Location (tried Xcode Default and Legacy). This is the Error Log:

> react-native run-ios
> info Found Xcode workspace "iPlayuListen.xcworkspace"
> info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace iPlayuListen.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme iPlayuListen -destination id=70107D6F-22AC-4326-A24C-EE0F879B7DE6")
> ............................................................................
> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening iPlayuListen.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Command line invocation:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace iPlayuListen.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme iPlayuListen -destination id=70107D6F-22AC-4326-A24C-EE0F879B7DE6
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Using build description from disk
> PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'iPlayuListen' from project 'iPlayuListen')
> cd /Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios
> /bin/sh -c /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh
> Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded!
> Ld /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.app/iPlayuListen normal (in target 'iPlayuListen' from project 'iPlayuListen')
> cd /Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios12.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVLinearGradient -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoringSSL-GRPC -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Glog -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlL/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-slider -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-spinkit -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-track-player -L/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-video -L/Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios/Pods/CocoaLibEvent/lib -L/Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib -F/Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -filelist /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iPlayuListen.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iPlayuListen_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBVLinearGradient -lBoringSSL-GRPC -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseDatabase -lFirebaseFirestore -lFirebaseInstallations -lFirebaseInstanceID -lFirebaseMessaging -lFirebaseStorage -lFlipper -lFlipper-DoubleConversion -lFlipper-Folly -lFlipper-Glog -lFlipper-PeerTalk -lFlipper-RSocket -lFlipperKit -lFolly -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleUtilities -lPromisesObjC -lProtobuf -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCMaskedView -lRNCPushNotificationIOS -lRNFBApp -lRNFBAuth -lRNFBDatabase -lRNFBFirestore -lRNFBMessaging -lRNFBStorage -lRNFastImage -lRNGestureHandler -lRNImageCropPicker -lRNInAppBrowser -lRNReanimated -lRNScreens -lRNSharedElement -lRNSnackbar -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lReactNativeART -lSDWebImage -lSDWebImageWebPCoder -lTOCropViewController -lYoga -lYogaKit -labseil -lc++ -lcrypto -levent -levent_core -levent_extra -levent_pthreads -lgRPC-C++ -lgRPC-Core -lglog -licucore -lleveldb-library -llibwebp -lnanopb -lreact-native-blur -lreact-native-camera -lreact-native-image-picker -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lreact-native-slider -lreact-native-spinkit -lreact-native-track-player -lreact-native-video -lsqlite3 -lssl -lstdc++ -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreTelephony -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework ImageIO -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Photos -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework UserNotifications -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/iPlayuListen.app-Simulated.xcent -lPods-iPlayuListen -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iPlayuListen_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.app/iPlayuListen
> ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'
> ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers'
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers", referenced from:
> *swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AVPlayerObserver.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(RNTrackPlayer.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AVPlayerItemObserver.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(Track.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(APError.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AudioItem.o)
> *swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AudioPlayer.o)
> ...
> (maybe you meant: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers*$_react_native_track_player)
> "_*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftCoreMIDI", referenced from:
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AVPlayerObserver.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(RNTrackPlayer.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AVPlayerItemObserver.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(Track.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(APError.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AudioItem.o)
> _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player in libreact-native-track-player.a(AudioPlayer.o)
> ...
> (maybe you meant: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$*swiftCoreMIDI*$_react_native_track_player)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'OpenSSL-Universal' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'RNImageCropPicker-QBImagePicker' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'CocoaLibEvent' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'react-native-video' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'SDWebImageWebPCoder' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseDatabase' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flipper' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'react-native-blur' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flipper-Folly' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'react-native-spinkit' from project 'Pods')
> iPlays-MBP:ipul-rn-ios-app iplayulisten$ npm run ios
> iplayulisten@0.0.2 ios /Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app
> react-native run-ios
> info Found Xcode workspace "iPlayuListen.xcworkspace"
> info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace iPlayuListen.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme iPlayuListen -destination id=70107D6F-22AC-4326-A24C-EE0F879B7DE6")
> ...............................................................................
> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening iPlayuListen.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Command line invocation:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace iPlayuListen.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme iPlayuListen -destination id=70107D6F-22AC-4326-A24C-EE0F879B7DE6
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Using build description from disk
> PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'iPlayuListen' from project 'iPlayuListen')
> cd /Users/iplayulisten/Projects/IPUL/2020/ipul-rn-ios-app/ios
> /bin/sh -c /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iPlayuListen.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh
> Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded!
> ** BUILD FAILED **
> The following build commands failed:
> Ld /Users/iplayulisten/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPlayuListen-auaptgmjpfqixkdtzqrvwqgmoqla/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPlayuListen.app/iPlayuListen normal
> (1 failure)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! iplayulisten@0.0.2 ios: `react-native run-ios`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the iplayulisten@0.0.2 ios script.

Comment: did you tried to remove pods folder and reinstall pod `cd ios && pod install`?

Comment: you can find answer in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725042/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error today.
This worked for me.
please run this command

```
cd ios && pod install
```